# GDAL: How to build an image pyramid starting from the base

Tags: gdal, image-pyramids

Normally I would create an Image Pyramid using *gdal_retile.py* on one large image or a set of large images.

I want to do the opposite. I have all the zoomed in tiles on the base level and I want to build (mosaic) my tiles into the rest of the levels required to build a pyramid. As *GIS-Jonathan* assumes I want to have the lower resolution tiles for zooming out.

```
                      ^      <- I want these
                     /_\     <-      :
                    /___\    <-      :
                   /_____\   <-      :
                  /_______\  <- I want these
                 /_________\ <- I have this level!
```

**Can this be done using GDAL or similar?**

I guess this would be the same as interupting *gdal_retile.py* just when the lowest level is finished and telling it to continue from the next level. But I don't know if this is possible?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to do or why. Are you saying you have a collection of images that form the lowest-resolution level of a pyramid, and you want to generate higher-resolution levels from them?

Comment: I take it as reading he's got the highest resolution (the super-zoomed in tiles), and wants to create the pyramids for them when zoomed out (lower resolution). This is why he wants to mosaic them together. Makes sense; don't know how to do it myself though. ;-)

Comment: @MerseyViking: It was very clear in my head :) But outside my head it might be less clear and I have tried to graphically show what I want.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan: You're right, but I had preferred a *this is how I always do it* ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a little bit complicated but you can do as follows:

1. Merge all the tiles by making larger pieces.
2. make all pieces coordinated with gdal_translate.
3. create .vrt (Virtual Dataset) file with gdalbuildvrt from all coordinated pieces.
4. use gdal2tiles for creating lower level tiles from your vrt file.

i hope it helps you...